# Does an isomorphism between extension of scalars implies an isomorphism of original modules

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, adjoint-functors, local-rings, module-isomorphism

Let $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$ be the local ring of formal power series in $n$ variables and let $\mathfrak{m}=(t_1, ..., t_n)$ be its unique maximal ideal. Let $M$ and $N$ be flat $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$-modules. If there be an isomorphism of $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$-modules (respectively of $\mathbb C$-modules)
$$\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]/\mathfrak{m}\otimes_{\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]}M\cong\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]/\mathfrak{m}\otimes_{\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]}N,$$

can we conclude if there is an isomorphism of $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$-modules $$M\cong N?$$

Answer (score 4):

Consider the quotient field $Q$ of $\Bbb C[[t_1,\ldots,t_n]]$, then both $Q$ and $Q^2$ are flat modules such that the tensor product in question is zero, but $Q$ and $Q^2$ are not isomorphic as modules over $\Bbb C[[t_1,\ldots,t_n]]$.

Comment: Great counterexample. Thanks.